# Why does my Alexa Skill stop with an error sound?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

First, I should clarify that I have the built-in Fallback intent set up properly and it triggers every time when I try to issue a rubbish command.

The problem occurs when I issue a command that is defined in a custom slot. For example, I have a custom slot type with the following slot values defined: apple, tomato, onion.

This slot type is added in a custom intent with the following utterances: Information about {food}, info about {food}.

So, in the intent utterances, I have not defined an utterance for the slot alone, i.e. just {food}.

Now, when Alexa is expecting a command, if I say just "apple", it gives an error tone and stops the skill without any error information. I realized that this happens when Alexa can't map the utterance to any intent, but I cannot figure out why it is not triggering the Fallback intent when this happens.

I opened the Utterance Profiler and tried the command there and all I get is that no intents have been triggered with that utterance. For other utterances, in  this case if I use "orange" which is not defined in the slot types, it will map to the Fallback intent.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can solve this?

Comment: could you add code of your custom alexa skill?

Comment: @slawciu code is irrelevant in this case. The Utterance Profiler runs on the interaction model without using the endpoint to send requests to the backend.